# Dynamically add amount to cart in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am very new to this community. kindly help me to get resolve form wordpress related query.

I am working on woocommerce website and need to add a service for ex:"electricity bill payment" . So, user has to dynamically add the amount and it should add to the card and reduced from his main wallet.

Is there any plugin or extension for this dynamically price added by this enduser ?

Plz suggest me and sorry for my bad english.

Many thanks,
sai

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53280/woocommerce-add-a-product-to-cart-programmatically-via-js-or-php

Comment: http://www.remicorson.com/add-custom-fee-to-woocommerce-cart-dynamically/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() { 
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Custom', 'woocommerce'), 5 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

Would you please add above code in your active theme `functions.php` ? but it will be applied on over all cart.

Comment: Tanq so much frnds , let me try :)

Comment: @VinodSelvaraj If this answer would be helpful to you then please mark it as approved so it could be helpful for others.